# How to create circular progress bar like below image in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[image]

I want to create this circular progress bar with animation and working on percentage

Comment: What does these 3 different circles represent? None of them are at 30% of circumference of the circle.

Comment: You can use these packages:

https://pub.dev/packages/step_progress_indicator or
https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator

Answer (score 0):

You can either achieve this using `CustomPaint` to draw it yourself (recommended), or perhaps using a `Stack` to put 3 different-sized `CircularProgressIndicator`s on top of each other.

It's not difficult to custom paint this: for each ring, you can first draw a grey circle as the background, then draw a colored arc path. You can round the ends by setting `Paint()..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round`.